# add a new column in Impala to update complex type

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, impala

I have a table with complex types in it's schema for instance:

```
address   ARRAY<STRUCT<street:STRING, state:STRING, names:ARRAY<STRING>, zip:INT>>
```

I wonder how I can change it to

```
address   ARRAY<STRUCT<street:STRING, city:STRING, state:STRING, names:ARRAY<STRING>, zip:INT>>
```

with an alter query?

Comment: where the new column comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use ALTER and CHANGE:

```
ALTER table name_of_table CHANGE address address ARRAY<STRUCT<street:STRING, city:STRING, state:STRING, names:ARRAY<STRING>, zip:INT>>
```